# C# Single filtering routine for List of two different classes by the same Property

Tags: c#, generics

There are two classes:

```
public class A {
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
    public string template { get; set; }
}


public class B {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string template { get; set; }
}
```

The routine I want to create will receive either `List<A>` or `List<B>` and apply some filtering based on the `template` property. The templates to avoid in `A`'s are: "b", "bb", "bbb", and templates to avoid in `B`'s are: "a", "aa", "aaa".

So I do something like this:

```
static List<A> filterAsByTemplate(List<A> listOfA, string skipInAList, char separator) {
    foreach (string template in skipInAList.Split(separator)) {
        listOfA.RemoveAll(x => x.template.Equals(template));
    }
    return listOfA;
}

static List<B> filterBsByTemplate(List<B> listOfB, string skipInBList, char separator) {
    foreach (string template in skipInBList.Split(separator)) {
        listOfB.RemoveAll(x => x.template.Equals(template));
    }
    return listOfB;
}
```

where

```
string skipInAList = "b;bb;bbb";
string skipInBList = "a;aa;aaa";
char separator = ';';
```

How can I combine `filterAsByTemplate` and `filterBsByTemplate` ?

Comment: Not a single Linq method in your code. Nice question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an Interface that you use for filtering, than implement a filter Method that does consume a list of this interface implementations.

```
public interface IFilterable
{
    string FilterProperty { get; }
}

public class A : IFilterable
{
    //implementation
}

public class B : IFilterable
{
    //Implementation
}

//Declaring Filter as extension method is possible aswell:
//static IEnumerable<T> Filter(this IEnumerable<T> source, string criteria) 
static IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> source, string criteria) 
       where T : IFilterable
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
       if(item.FilterProperty.Contains(criteria)) yield return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "combining" you mean to rule them both using a single method, you'll have to have a common type to both `A` and `B` with the `template` property, and the parameter to the method would be `List<BaseTypeOfAB>`.

Something like:

```
public abstract class BaseTypeOfAB
{
    public string template { get; set; }
}

public class A : BaseTypeOfAB
{
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
}

public class B : BaseTypeOfAB
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

static List<T> filterByTemplate<T>(List<T> list, string skipInList, char separator) where T : BaseTypeOfAB
{
    foreach (string template in skipInList.Split(separator))
        list.RemoveAll(x => x.template.Equals(template));

    return list;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the structure of your classes, you can pass a generic delegate instead:

```
static List<T> filterByTemplate<T, TProp>(List<T> list, Func<T, TProp> predicate, string skipInList, char separator)
{
    foreach (string template in skipInList.Split(separator)) {
        list.RemoveAll(x => predicate(x).Equals(template));

    return list;
}

// Usage:
var listOfAs = new List<A>();
var listOfBs = new List<B>();

filterByTemplate(listOfAs, x => x.template, "a;aa;aaa", ';');
filterByTemplate(listOfBs, x => x.template, "b;bb;bbb", ';');
```

Comment: You should use interfaces when possible instead of base classes. Base classes are a precious resource not to be squandered away like this.

Comment: @Aron, For me (and many others), interfaces represent a contract. In this case, the `template` property represents data and not behavior hence it's definitely a personal preference (and in my opinion, a better one) to go with base class. Do you have any evidence backing the claim that "Base classes are a precious resource not to be squandered away like this"?

Comment: a) you only get to inherit one class b) vlookup cost

Comment: @Aron a) "You only get to inherit one class" - That's an artificial problem. b) "vlookup cost" - Since the `template` property is not marked as `abstract` or `virtual` I'm not sure virtual table lookup is actually involved here and interface dispatching has its cost as well. In runtime, the CLR can handle them both easily and efficiently and picking up on `interface / class` doesn't add anything to the actual Q/A here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Define a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseTypeOfAB
{
    public abstract string template {get;set;}
}
```

And the both `A` and `B` inherits from `BaseTypeOfAB`. Like this:

```
public class A : BaseTypeOfAB {
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
    public override string template { get; set; }
}


public class B : BaseTypeOfAB {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public override string template { get; set; }
}
```

The write a generic function that takes the list and the skip. Use like to see if the values do not contain in the skip. Like this:

```
static List<TClass> filterByTemplate<TClass>(List<TClass> ls,string skipInList,char seperator) where TClass: BaseTypeOfAB
{
    return ls.Where (w =>!skipInList.Split(seperator).Contains(w.template)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You should use interfaces when possible instead of base classes. Base classes are a precious resource not to be squandered away like this.